# How to make the actionName available for a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, interceptor, spock

In an Interceptor's `before()` I'm doing something specific based on the `actionName` but when ran from the test the `actionName` is null:

Test:

```
void "test"() {
    when:
        withRequest(controller: 'test1', action: 'test2')

    then:
        interceptor.doesMatch()
        interceptor.before()
}
```

How do I populate the `actionName` in the test?

Grails 3.1.6

Answer (score 0):

```
void "test"() {
    when:
        withRequest(controller: 'test1', action: 'test2')
        request.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.ACTION_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, 'test2')

    then:
        interceptor.doesMatch()
        interceptor.before()
}
```

This works for me, although I would prefer a more automatic way, I expected the `withRequest` method to do this.